Run Gazebo simulation on HPC cluster
I'm trying to run Gazebo simulation with ROS2 in a HPC cluster but I have problems running it properly. More in detail I'm using a Singularity/Apptainer container generated from a .def file and can run everything correctly on a personal laptop.
When I execute the command ign gazebo -s world_file.sdf I don't get any error but at the same time I'm not able to see any Gazebo topic or get any feedback from the terminal.
Do you have any suggestions that can help me?
